# Get last appearance of a node

Tags: xml, actionscript-3, e4x

Given

```
<nodeList>
    <crazyNode>Data to be overwrited</crazyNode>
    <simpleNode>Normal data</simpleNode>
    <crazyNode>Actual data</crazyNode>
</nodeList>
```

I want to get the last `crazyNode` (the one which contains *Actual data*).

I know how to access the first node, for example:

```
nodeList.crazyNode[0]
```

And I guess a solution would be

```
nodeList.crazyNode[nodeList.crazyNode.length() - 1]
```

But for some reason I don't like doing that, too verbose and maybe there's a method more elegant.

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

You could refactor the code to be more readable, but that is the way to do it. Since the problem itself is getting the actual index, you could just declare a new variable to hold that value, like so:

```
var lastCrazyNodeIndex: int = nodeList.crazyNode.length() - 1;
```

You can then write a method for getting the last item, here's an idea:

```
public function getLastCrazyNode(nodeList:XML):Object
{
    var lastCrazyNodeIndex: int = nodeList.crazyNode.length() - 1;

    if( lastCrazyNodeIndex != -1 )
        return nodeList[ lastCrazyNodeIndex ];

    return null;
}
```

Even if it's the same idea, it's more readable.

Answer (score 1):

You could use something like:

```
nodeList.crazyNode.(childIndex()==length()-1);
```

Though it may not be any "prettier"...